# missing _version, _deleted, and _lastChangedAt fields in the database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, schema, aws-amplify

I'm working on a React Native app, that uses an Amplify API to connect to a DynamoDB table.

I use DataStore in the app for offline data handling, and for a while some previous versions of the app set the API to be unsyncable, which resulted some of our data being saved without `_version`, `_deleted`, and `_lastChangedAt` fields.

I just fixed the error to make the API syncable again, but some of our data is missing those fields now, and I'm getting error messages when I try to query the table from the app.

```
    Object {
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'Int' within parent 'Capture' (/listCaptures/items[18]/_version)",
      "path": Array [
        "listCaptures",
        "items",
        18,
        "_version",
      ],
    },
    Object {
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'AWSTimestamp' within parent 'Capture' (/listCaptures/items[18]/_lastChangedAt)",     
      "path": Array [
        "listCaptures",
        "items",
        18,
        "_lastChangedAt",
      ],
    },
```

I can't just apply a one time fix to the database, because there are older version clients out there connected to the database, keep generating records with the missing fields.

I want to do some kind of check when the new version of the program starts to fix the "broken" records in the table, but first I need to be able to query it from the app.

This is one of my tables in the qraphql schema:

```
type DatabaseConversion @model {
    id: ID!
    userID: String!
    ConversionID: String!
}
```

This is the auto generated query that throws an error when the `_version`, `_deleted`, or `_lastChangedAt` fields are missing:

```
export const listDatabaseConversions = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListDatabaseConversions(
    $filter: ModelDatabaseConversionFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listDatabaseConversions(
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        userID
        ConversionID
        _version
        _deleted
        _lastChangedAt
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
      startedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

My question is, that how do I define a custom query in the schema that is only looking for the neccessary fields, and it can find all the records without throwing an error?

I think if I try to update the record with it's current content in the new version of the app, that will automatically create the missing fields.

Comment: I am getting the same error, I don't know maybe my configuration is incorrect. Can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: My API wasn't set to be syncable. Add "ResolverConfig" here:

amplify/backend/api/captureStore/transform.conf.json:
{
    "Version": 5,
    "ElasticsearchWarning": true,
    "ResolverConfig": {
        "project": {
            "ConflictHandler": "AUTOMERGE",
            "ConflictDetection": "VERSION"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to copy the auto generated query code, to a new file e.g: `src/customGraphQL/customQueries.js`. Rename the query, and remove the unnecessary fields, and it can be used just as an auto generated query.

```
export const customListDatabaseConversions = /* GraphQL */ `
  query CustomListDatabaseConversions(
    $filter: ModelDatabaseConversionFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listDatabaseConversions(
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        userID
        ConversionID
      }
      nextToken
      startedAt
    }
  }
`;
```